# time value in org-table formula

Tags: org-mode, org-table

Is there any way to have time constant in an Org spreadsheet formula? For example, i would like to have something like this:

```
@>$3=@>$5-'08:00:00'*vcount(@2..@-1)
```

to calculate how much longer I've been at work than I have to be :) The `@>$5` is the total sum of hours I've been at work and `@2..@-1` are the rows with days I've been working.

Comment: _“to calculate how much longer i've been at work than i have to be”_
while this doesn’t answer the question, the best way to achieve this
goal might be to use
[`org-clock-in`](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/org-clock-in).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Org mode formulas use Calc mode under the covers and Calc has a format for specifying hours, minutes and seconds. See [the Emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/calc.html#HMS-Formats).

You can therefore use `8@` to specify 8 hours, 0 minutes and 0 seconds.

I found that to get it to work I had to calculate the vcount first. So something like this:

```
@>$3=vcount(@2..@-1) * (@>$5-8@)
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me at all :( i get this result: http://pastebin.com/eBe6nuqT

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do since in your paste vcount(@2..@-1) returns 1 and @>$5 is an empty/blank field. So the formula results in 1 * (0 - 8 hours). The result shown in @>$3 is quite correctly -8@ 0' 0." i.e. -8 hours, 0 minutes and 0 seconds. See http://pastebin.com/Xzam2S8m where I have changed your time format to the calc format, summed it up into @>$5 and subtrated 8 hours from it. (vcount(@2..@-1) is still returning 1 though).

Comment: thanks, this works if you don't use HH:MM:SS format, which is fine for my case